# Revert an equation performed with LCM

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By doing the LCM (Least Common Multiple) in this:

$1-\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

we reach the result:

$\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1+ e^{-x}}$

But what would be the reverse process?

Assuming I didn't know the result, is it possible to go from this

$\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1+ e^{-x}}$

to that?

$1-\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

I don't know how, Could you help me by showing the steps ?

Comment: In some sense the equation that defines division is $a/b=c+(a-bc)/b$ for any $c$. So you can use that with $c=1$ here to run this process in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{-x} - (1+e^{-x}) + (1+e^{-x})}{1+e^{-x}}
= 1 + \frac{e^{-x} - (1+e^{-x})}{1+e^{-x}} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}= \frac{1+e^{-x}-1}{1+e^{-x}}= \frac{1+e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=1-\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$